# YARN/NPM: installing package versions that are compatible to certain dependency version

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

Let's imagine that I have the following dependencies section in `package.json` file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "A": "1.0.0"
  }
```

As well, let's assume that the current version of package A is `3.0.0`. But I need version `1.0.0` of `A` in my project, so I explicitly specify it in `package.json`.

Given that, let's assume that I need to have another package `B` in my project that is dependent on `A`. The latest version of `B` is also `3.0.0`, but it is incompatible with `"A": "1.0.0"`. The correct version of `B` that is compatible with `"A": "1.0.0"` would be `"B": "1.0.0"`.

The question is -

> how do I detect what version of package `B` is compatible with `"A":"1.0.0"`?
>
> Is there a way to automatically install the versions of
>   packages, that are dependent on `A` and a compatible with `"A": "1.0.0"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There's no way to install compatible package while installing node packages. You must specify them manually in package.json.

---

But, you may try the following:

1. Define the specific package version in package.json for only one of your main package.
2. Install the dependency (main package). `npm install`
3. Don't specify the dependency module version of the main package.
4. Install dependency. `npm install DEPENDENCY_PACKAGE`

This might work because as far as I remember once I had defined the main package and not its dependent package and did the preceding approach and was installed compatible version. (I had defined node engine version. But I'm not fully sure if this approach works with other packages as well.)

Just try and let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

`B` should define its own dependency on a specific version of `A`, e.g. `0.0.1`. In that case, when you do `npm/yarn install`, given you have `package.json` like:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "A": "1.0.0"
    "B": "1.0.0"
  }
```

1. `A@1.0.0`, `B@1.0.0` will be installed,

since B declared it needs `A@0.0.1`,

2. `A@0.0.1` will be installed too, but under `node_modules/B`.

Therefore, if the dependencies you use are well written, you should not need to manually handle these kind of problem.

More information on this behavior can be found [here](https://medium.com/learnwithrahul/understanding-npm-dependency-resolution-84a24180901b).

Answer (score 1):

If you force the B dependencies in your project, npm install the version that you forced.

E.g.

```
"dependencies": {
    "A": "1.0.0",
    "B": "1.0.0"
}
```

NPM will install B 1.0.0 in your project.

To say that I tried to create a project with

```
...
"dependencies": {
   "rxjs": "5.0.1",
   "chai": "4.1.0"
},
...
```

Rxjs have inside the chai package dependency fixed at version 4.1.2.

I forced the 4.1.0 on my `package.json` and npm installed the version 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem when trying to install style-loader for webpack 4.

> how do I detect what version of package B is compatible with "A":"1.0.0"?

Attempting to install it using `npm install style-loader` tells me

> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer webpack@"^5.0.0" from style-loader@3.3.1

Tried decreasing the version number until the install succeeded:

`npm install style-loader@\<3.3.0`

> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer webpack@"^5.0.0" from style-loader@3.2.1
> npm ERR! node_modules/style-loader
> npm ERR!   style-loader@"<3.3.0" from the root project

`npm install style-loader@\<3.2.0` etc, until the module installed.

package.json indicates that version 2.0.0 was installed.